# Drupal - Disable SAML login in local instance

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I am very new to Drupal. I have done the local setup and the front end is working fine. Now I need to login to the admin interface. Seems like there is a SAML configuration and when I try to access the /user/login page it is showing the following error :

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
```

I can see there is one simplesaml folder in the codebase and I think this is handling the SAML login. Now in the local setup, I don't need to use SSO, but not sure how to disable this extension. I have checked in the core.extension.yml, but the fllowing extensions set to 0 there and hence I think this is not activated.

```
   basic_auth: 0
   externalauth: 0
   simplesamlphp_auth: 0
```

Also in my local configuration `settings.local.php`, it is set as `false`:

`$config['simplesamlphp_auth.settings']['activate'] = FALSE;`

It will be very much helpful if somebody can guide me in the right direction. I have access to the database, but not sure where I need to make changes. This might be a simple thing, but I am blocked here.

The Error I am seeing the logs is like this :

```
Uncaught PHP Exception SimpleSAML\Error\Exception: "Could not find the metadata of an IdP with entity ID 'localhost:default:entityId'" at /vendor/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/modules/saml/lib/Auth/Source/SP.php line 317
```

Answer (score 0):

You can login to Drupal using a console command.
Open a terminal, navigate to the project folder like

```
cd ~/project/my-project/web/
```

Then run

```
drush uli
```

the output will be a one time login link.